# React button not adding component to the page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The Add item button should trigger a pop up form with input fields, but the form is not rendering. It shows blank page on rendering just with the button.

```
import './App.css';

const InventoryManager = () => {
  
        dispatch(addItem(newItem));

        // Reset the input fields
        setItemName('');
        setItemDescription('');
        setItemPrice('');
        setItemImage('');

        // Close the popup form
        setShowPopup(false);
    };

    const handleClearForm = () => {
        // Clear the input fields
        setItemName('');
        setItemDescription('');
        setItemPrice('');
        setItemImage('');
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Inventory Manager</h1>

            <div id="buttons">
                <button onClick={() => setShowPopup(true)}>Add Item</button>
            </div>

            {showPopup && (
                <div id="add-item-popup">
                    <div id="popup-header">
                        <h2>Add Item</h2>
                        <button id="close-button" onClick={() => setShowPopup(false)}>
                            X
                        </button>
                    </div>
                   
      
                    </form>
                </div>
            )}

            <div id="inventory-gallery">{/* Render inventory items here */}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default InventoryManager;
```

Tried implementing in a single file and in different component files but form still not rendering.

Comment: What is the code for setShowPopup?

Comment: You should have `const [ showPopup, setShowPopup ] = useState(false)` somewhere... I you do not, then you should have a bunch of errors in console.

Comment: This code seems to be incomplete. Unless you omitted certain parts of the file from this post, this code should not work.

Answer (score 0):

First, your file format is incorrect. For example, there are extra bracket in line 15. On the other hand, you have used undefined functions in your code, such as function dispatch and setItemName. I recommend reading the official [React documentation](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) about hooks.